# article wrapper class that locks down some options, passes others through

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I'm writing a wrapper document class that starts with `article` and adds a bunch of customizations (required for a particular journal style).  One of the requirements is to lock down certain options:

```
\documentclass{thisjournal}
```

should behave the same as

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
% plus some more stuff
```

and

```
\documentclass[12pt]{thisjournal} % or 'onecolumn', or 'a4paper, etc
```

should produce an error message, but other options should be passed through, e.g.

```
\documentclass[draft]{thisjournal} % should turn on overfull rules
```

I've gotten as far as

```
\ProvidesClass{thisjournal}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\ClassError{testclass}{Ten point text is required.}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
```

but I am unenthusiastic about having to write `\DeclareOption` boilerplate for every possible font and paper size option other than `10pt` and `letterpaper`.  (Is it even *possible* to enumerate that set?)  Surely there is a better way?

Comment: Which set is smaller: those to pass through or those not to? Is one (or both) well defined?

Comment: The locked-down options are the ones I showed: `10pt`, `letterpaper`, and `twocolumn`.  I have no idea how many other options `article.cls` has, and people probably do still want to use the generic "options on the `\documentclass` line get passed to all packages even if not recognized as class options" mechanism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on Gonzalo's answer, you can iterate through the options you want to kill. (As th base classes do not use key-value methods, it's not like you only have to kill the 'key' part, regrettably.)

```
\@for\@tempa:=10pt,12pt,14pt,letterpaper,a4paper,onecolumn,twocolumn\do{%
  \DeclareOption{\@tempa}{\OptionNotUsed}%    
}
```

Comment: For other reasons I suspect I am going to have to start from scratch, after all; but this seems like the best answer to the question as posed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\OptionNotUsed`; for example,

```
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\OptionNotUsed}
```

Comment: That makes the boilerplate less repetitive, but there's still a couple dozen `\DeclareOption` lines to write; it's *that* that I'm hoping to avoid somehow.