# How can I force some options and discard others in a custom class?

Tags: memoir, paper-size, documentclass-writing, class-options

I'm creating a document class based upon `memoir`. For this, I allow several
class options to be passed to my code. Options that are not recognized will
simply be passed to `memoir`.

Now my question is: how can I force `a4paper` even if the user of my class passes `letterpaper` as an option?
In other words: is there a possibility to disable the other document size options (`letterpaper`, `a5paper`, `ebook`, etc.) while keeping it possible to pass on options such as `ms` or `fleqn`?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21171/mutually-exclusive-options-in-packages

Comment: also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64710/article-wrapper-class-that-locks-down-some-options-passes-others-through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
% declare options that should be passed to your code
% ...

% now specify which memoir options should not be used, using the following helper macro
\newcommand\warningoptionnotused@myclass
{%
  \OptionNotUsed%
  \ClassWarning{myclass}%
  {%
    Option '\CurrentOption'\space is incompatible with class
    `myclass' and will be ignored.
  }
}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}{\warningoptionnotused@myclass}
\DeclareOption{a5paper}{\warningoptionnotused@myclass}
\DeclareOption{ebook}{\warningoptionnotused@myclass}
% do the same for all options that should be discarded...

% pass all other options to memoir
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}

% process options
\ProcessOptions\relax

% then load memoir with the desired options
\LoadClass[a4paper]{memoir}
```